# Necessity for "main" (java)

Tags: java

I know its looks crazy. But, anyways. We all know the way main method should be : 
`public static void main(String args[])`. Reason is

- `public`: The method can be accessed from the code outside the class in which it is defined(invoked from JVM)
- `static`: The method can be accessed without instantiating the class in which it is declared.
  Again, this keyword also allows the JVM to invoke this method without instantiating the class.
- `void`: The method does not return any data.

So, whats the necessity for "main" here. Even if there is another method say `public static void entry(String args[])`, why jvm will not invoke this method. It gives compiler issues saying  it couldnt find the main method. Even this `public static void entry(String args[])` compiles to the above mentioned 3 rules.

Comment: Because, too bad, the spec says it should be `main`.

Comment: How should the JVM know that it has to invoke the `entry` method? If you make the name variable, you have to specify somewhere which method to call.

Comment: "It gives compiler issues saying it couldnt find the `main` method." You say that as if that was a *bad* thing.

Answer (score 3):

Go ahead. Implement your own command-line driver that uses the JNI invocation interface to launch a program at whatever entrypoint appeals to you.

The special character of 'main' is purely a question of the Java command-line program. The designers made a choice. Their reasons are not wildly interesting; it's not going to change. Well, to be precise, you could join the openjdk project and try to sell them a feature.

Comment: FWIW - writing your own launcher using JNI is fairly simple...  I'd recommend it as a good exercise.  It's also good to have your own executable if you deploy apps the old fashion way.

Answer (score 2):

The method has to be called `main` because there needs to be something to specify that the method is the entry point method. Not just any `public static void` method with a single `String[]` argument should be considered an entry point... you might want such a method that does something different. Also, by specifying a specific name the method must have, there is a guarantee that a single class can have at most a single entry point method. You could have:

```
class Something {
  public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
  public static void parseArgs(String[] args) { ... }
  public static void displayInvalidArgsMessage(String[] args) { ... }
}
```

If you tried to run that class, how would it pick the method to use unless there were some rule? With annotations today, one option might be to require a `public static void` method with a `String[]` arg annotated with `@EntryPoint` or some such... but the `main` solution is still better than this, because the compiler can enforce the restriction of one `main` method per class using its normal method signature rules, while multiple methods could be given the same annotation. Not to mention the fact that there needed to be a way to run programs long before annotations were added and the precedent from C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the reasons given by others, there was/is one more - nontechnical, but probably more important than the technical considerations -: making Java easy to learn (for C++ programmers, primarily). Back when Java started, their creators wanted to make it an easy language and help developers convert from existing languages. Since the primary existing OO language in use was C++ at that time, and there the entry point is called `main` (which is indeed, as @Felix noted, inherited from C to make C++ backward compatible as much as possible), they used the same name in Java too. Note that since then, C# adopted the same convention as well (albeit in a somewhat more general form), for the same reason.

Comment: And C got it from BCPL and BCPL got it from Brian Kerninghan and Dennis Ritchie.

Comment: Is BCPL not using start() for that?

Comment: @Costis, were K&R involved in the design of BCPL? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCPL) names only Martin Richards.

Comment: I don't know! Could be. It was a joke. But before C, there was B that was inspired by BCPL. Wikipedia say "B is a programming language that was developed at Bell Labs. It is almost extinct, as it was replaced with the C language. It was mostly the work of Ken Thompson, with contributions from Dennis Ritchie, and first appeared circa 1969."

Comment: @Costis, also, between BCPL and C there was yet B. The latter already involving Ritchie.

Comment: @Peter, you are absolutely right. It was a quick comment for fun.

Comment: @Costis, OK, it just sounded too serious :-)